# Bold text not working on Android Enthusiast site

Tags: bug, status-declined, markdown, markdown-rendering

I am bolding certain text using the format **Bold Text** (text enveloped in two asterisks - before and after) but it's not showing as bolded.

Please advise

Please see this post as reference:
[Post with issue](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54802/flashing-galaxy-tab-2-7-0-verizon-branded-hangs-on-download)

The words **Edit** and **Edit2** should be bolded just like they are here.

Comment: They're both bolded and italicized for me...

Comment: Curious, I don't see the bolding, only the italics - Italicized the words because I don't see the bolding.  I am using Chrome, but I wouldn't think that should matter.

Comment: @AndroidAddict What version of Chrome are you using? It works fine in Chrome for me.

Comment: I agree with the answer posted here that it's the font.  Please see comments below for reference.  Chrome version 30.0.1599.69

Comment: Chrome does weird things with fonts

Comment: Why didn't you post this on the Android Meta?

Comment: Chrome for Android? Chrome for Windows? They're all (or at least should be) on v.30 on the standard channel. (For what it's worth, they look fine to me and I'm on Windows.)

Comment: In short, because I was unaware it existed.  There comes a point where the recursion of searching becomes too much.

Comment: See also http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/602/why-is-the-font-weight-bold/603#603

Comment: At this point in time, it's unfeasible to change the font configuration for the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using three asterisk on that post which results in ***italic bold*** text, which looks a bit thin on the Android site. You can just use two asterisk with result in plain **bold** text, which looks okay on the Android site.

This seems to be somewhat specific to the font used on Android, it is still bold for me but less noticeable than on other sites (this might look different on your computer, though).

The fonts used seem to be

```
Roboto,'Droid Sans','DroidSansRegular','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif
```

For me DroidSansRegular is used, so it is probably a problem with one of the other possible fonts.

Comment: Italicized the words because I don't see the bolding

Comment: I agree upon closer inspection it must be the font.  It's very subtle, but it does look bolded.